# Angular ng-repeat conditional wrap items in element (filter items in ng-repeat group)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to hide occupation name when filtered user is not found in some occupation.

**JS:**

```
$scope.contacts = [
    {name: 'John', occupation: 'occupation 1'},
    {name: 'George', occupation: 'occupation 2'},
    {name: 'Jeck', occupation: 'occupation 3'},
    {name: 'Paula', occupation: 'occupation 1'},
    {name: 'Scruath', occupation: 'occupation 3'}
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query">
<div ng-repeat="(key, occupation) in contacts | groupBy: 'occupation'">
    <p ng-bind="occupation[0].occupation"></p>
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="contact in occupation | filter:search">
            <p ng-bind="::contact.fullName"></p>
            <p ng-bind="::contact.email"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**RESULT:**

Occupation Name: "occupation 1"

- name: "John"
- name: "Paula"

Occupation Name: "occupation 2"

- name: "George"

Occupation Name: "occupation 3"

- name: "Jeck"
- name: "Scruath"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this you want if you write  occupation 1 on textbox then the result is

name: "John"
name: "Paula"

Comment: Exactly! But my problem is that the occupation of 2 and occupation 3 are not hiding

Comment: Actually filter implements contains search if you write occupation 1 then occupation 2 and occupation 3 data will hide

Comment: when you type the occupation 1 the name of "George" will be hide, but Occupation Name: "occupation 2" not hiding

Comment: `ng-repeat="(key, occupation) in contacts"` is the notation to use when working with (key,value) pairs in a main object, here you're using an array of objects. You should change your data model to fit your needs, like using a seperate datamodel to identify your contacts by occupations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solution to your problem:

- Use `ng-show` on the filtered array.
- Use the sorting on the top `ng-repeat`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/ha9792v9/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['angular.filter'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.contacts = [{
      name: 'John',
      occupation: 'occupation 1'
    }, {
      name: 'George',
      occupation: 'occupation 2'
    }, {
      name: 'Jeck',
      occupation: 'occupation 3'
    }, {
      name: 'Paula',
      occupation: 'occupation 1'
    }, {
      name: 'Scruath',
      occupation: 'occupation 3'
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="query">
    <h3>
    Filter with new array filtered
    </h3>
    <div ng-repeat="(key,occupation) in contacts| groupBy: 'occupation'" ng-show="filterOccupation.length">

      <p ng-bind="key"></p>
      <div>
        <div ng-repeat="contact in filterOccupation = (occupation|filter:query)">
          <p ng-bind="::contact.name"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3>
    Filter with extra filtered
    </h3>
    <div ng-repeat="(key,occupation) in contacts|filter:query | groupBy: 'occupation'">

      <p ng-bind="key"></p>
      <div>
        <div ng-repeat="contact in occupation|filter:query ">
          <p ng-bind="::contact.name"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```